# css - height 100% is not working

Tags: css

I have the following html markup:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="back">
        <div id="header">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
#header{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5p4bJ/)

But also the hundred percent height is not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make 100% height work you need to make sure your parent div also contain height 100%. So try this:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
#header{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#all,#back{
    height: 100%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5p4bJ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all parents of `#header` to have `height: 100%` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;

}
#header{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#all,#back{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

height:100% means it will occupy the full height of the parent element.In your scenario parent div's #all and #back doesn't have their own height defined.So you need to give height:100% to them also

```
#all,#back
{
  height:100%
}
```